# Distribution of the mean of Brownian motions

Tags: probability-distributions, normal-distribution, brownian-motion

Consider $Z_n = \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{B_k}{n}$ where each $B_k \sim N(0, k)$ is a Brownian motion. I'm trying to compute the distribution of $Z_n$. Obviously $EZ_n=0$. For $Var Z_n$, since $\mathbf{Cov}B_sB_t = \min\{s,t\},$ I derive
\begin{align}
Var Z_n &= \frac{1}{n^2}\bigg(\sum_kVar B_k + 2\sum_{i<j}\mathbf{Cov} B_i, B_j\bigg) \\
&= \frac{1}{n^2}\bigg(\binom{n}{2} + 1(n-1) + 2(n-2) + \ldots+(n-1)\bigg) \\
&= \frac{1}{n^2}\bigg(\binom{n}{2} + \binom{n+1}{3}\bigg) \\
&= \frac{1}{2}\bigg(1-\frac{1}{n}\bigg) + \frac{n}{6}\bigg(1-\frac{1}{n^2}\bigg)
\end{align}
So $Z_n \sim \mathbf{N\bigg(0, \frac{1}{2}\bigg(1-\frac{1}{n}\bigg) + \frac{n}{6}\bigg(1-\frac{1}{n^2}\bigg)\bigg)}$

There are two things that are a bit confusing: I never used the fact that $B_t - B_s \sim N(0, t-s)$ and the sum of dependent normal rvs is not always normal. I'm not sure how to use these facts though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linear combinations of jointly normal random variables are always normal. Once you use the fact that $EB_tB_s=\min \{t,s\}$ you don't need the fact that $B_t-B_s \sim N(0,t-s)$.

Comment: thanks, so my derivation is correct then?

Comment: @Alex Yes, it is correct.